# Assign current row value to previous row of panda dataframe after comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the panda dataframe in python below.

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   62295.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200926    12880.00  13000.00   14224.0
```

First, I want to detect which row falls on a Saturday based on column `Date_YMD`. Then, find out the volume value on this Saturday and assign this value to the previous row's `volume` if the previous row value is larger than current row value.

The final panda frame will look like this for the table above;

```
full_name  serial  Date_YMD        prc1     prc2    volume
 bottle_a  AX80    20200922    12874.50  12927.75   61023.0 
 bottle_a  AX80    20200923    12878.50  12926.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200924    12872.50  12928.75   61023.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200925    12885.50  12984.25   14224.0
 bottle_a  AX80    20200926    12880.00  13000.00   14224.0
```

Saturday volume can be obtained with the following code below;

```
df['Date_YMD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_YMD'], format='%Y%m%d')
sat_volume = df.loc[df['Date_YMD'].dt.dayofweek.eq(5), 'volume']
```

The problem is how do I assign this `sat_volume` to the previous row's `volume` accordingly after comparing the values?

I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create boolean masks `m1` and `m2` then use *boolean indexing* with these masks to fill the column `volume` where the condition specified by `m1` and `m2` is satisfied:

```
m1 = df['volume'] > df['volume'].shift(-1)
m2 = df['Date_YMD'].shift(-1).dt.weekday.eq(5)
df.loc[m1 & m2, 'volume'] = df['volume'].shift(-1)
```

---

```
  full_name serial   Date_YMD     prc1      prc2   volume
0  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-22  12874.5  12927.75  61023.0
1  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-23  12878.5  12926.75  61023.0
2  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-24  12872.5  12928.75  61023.0
3  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-25  12885.5  12984.25  14224.0
4  bottle_a   AX80 2020-09-26  12880.0  13000.00  14224.0
```